# I've some problem in the definition of primitive root in the Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, primitive-roots

In the book, he said that "A *primitive root* modulo a prime *p* is an integer *r* in $\mathbb Z_p$ such that every nonzero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a power of *r*."
It is very different to other definition of primitive root on the web, in which they all mentioned cogruence.
In the book I mentioned, there is an example that determine whether 2 and 3 are primitive roots modulo 11. It shows that 2<sup>4</sup>=5. I think it is wrong, it should be 2<sup>4</sup> **mod** 11=5. And the definition should be "A *primitive root* modulo a prime *p* is an integer *r* in $\mathbb Z_p$ such that every nonzero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a power of *r* modulo *p*."

How do you think about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is easy to see that the different definitions are equivalent, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). A primitive root modulo $p$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$.

Comment: What do you think $\mathbb Z_p$ means, if it isn't defined in terms of congruence?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In this book, it said $\mathbb Z_p$ is the set {0,1,...,p-1}. In the definition of primitive root, it just said every nonzero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a power of *r*. But in the example that determine whether 2 and 3 are primitive roots modulo 11, it shows that 2^4=5. I cannot understand it. I think it should be 2^4 **mod** 11=5. And the definition should be "every nonzero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a power of *r* modulo *p*"

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_p,$ multiplication is redefined as $a\cdot_p b= (ab)\bmod p.$ So $2^4=5,$ not $2^4\bmod 11=5.$ The modulo 11 is already taken into account by the system's definition of multiplication.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It explains the matter!

Comment: See the linked dupe for more on the meaning of $\Bbb Z_n$ and its relationship with congruences $\!\bmod n\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Your perplexity is legitimate, because the book mixes two common (very near, though strictly speaking non equivalent) definitions:

A [primitive root modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) is:

- an element $a$ of $\Bbb Z_n$ such that every invertible element of $\mathbb Z_n$ is a power of *a*.
- an integer $r$ such that every integer coprime to $n$ is congruent $\bmod n$ to a power of $r.$

The integers $r$ of the second definition are the elements of the congruence classes $a$ of the first one.

Comment: Both definitions are usual. Btw, in French we have two words: "inversible" for your multiplicative inverses, and "symétrisable" for your general inverses (for any binary operation, be it multiplication or addition or whatsoever).